# Make one ASP.NET Panel control visible on top of other content

Tags: asp.net, panel

I have a set of report filter panels that I would like to make optionally visible, one at a time.  However, when I set my panel's display attribute from 'none', to 'block', it understandably pushes other content down.  How can I float the panel over the other content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning or hide the element you want underneath it.  And if you will be doing server post backs between each change, you can use the "Visible" property to control whether the panel is even rendered to html in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

```
style="z-index: X; position: relative;"
```

where X is a number greater than all other z-indexes, i.e. 256.  If you haven't specified any, 1 should be high enough.